# copy constructor and shallow copy

Tags: c++, oop, copy-constructor, shallow-copy

I wrote the following code  to see shallow copy. I was expecting v2 to be a shallow copy of v1 since no copy construtor is defined , so I was hoping that changing v1.n would also cause  v2.n to change, but it didn't. What I am doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Vector
{
  public:
  int n;
  float *v;

  Vector();

};
Vector::Vector()
{
  v = new float[100];
  n = 100;
  cout<<"Constructor called"<<endl;
}


int main()
{
  Vector v1;
  v1.n=5;
  Vector v2=v1;
  v1.n=6;
  cout <<"Vector v1 has n value: "<<v1.n<<endl;
  cout <<"Vector v2 has n value: "<<v2.n<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want the shallow copy behaviour make n a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, it's just that a shallow copy of an `int` is still a copy.

`v1`, and `v2` have their own copies of `n`, and changing one won't change the other.

If you want to see the shallow copy behavior that you expect, use the pointer `v`. This copy *only* copies the pointer, not the memory it's pointing to, i.e. changing one of the values pointed at by `v1.v` will change the values pointed at by `v2.v`.

Comment: So if I give values to the array's elements, I should see the shallow copy behavior on them, but not on the data members not involving pointers like an int?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. edited answer as well to make that clear.